# How do I get an email address from the LinkedIn API

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I've already enabled the permission to access a user's email address.

[Permission to access email address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3nBU.png)

I've tried changing my email address and the privacy settings.

I'm definitely requesting the right field, because an error isn't caught and all fields except the email address are returned.

```
String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-urls::(original),industry,positions,email-address)";
```

[JSON result returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1YJf.png)

But neither of them work. What could be the reason why?

Comment: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address)?format=json Can you try this link in this console https://apigee.com/console/linkedin ?. Also you have to give authentication as oAuth2.

Comment: @sunilsunny it worked on there. I selected oAuth2 from the drop-down and it just asked me to log in. Weirdly though, my profile ID is different to the one returned from using that link above.

Comment: So you need to implement oAuth2  authentication in your app.. Not sure about it though.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I don't know how to do that. Could you send me a link of a guide if you know of any?

Comment: You can start here https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk. They are providing a SDK use that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a stupid mistake.

Turns out I forgot to set permission to access the Email Address, in the code.

```
// Build the list of member permissions our LinkedIn session requires
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE);
}
```

Changed to:

```
// Build the list of member permissions our LinkedIn session requires
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS);
}
```